# React search and filter component not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a search and filter component. I want when input keypress enter get data on search result page.

When I checked checkbox how can I filtered data in search result page?

Here is sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-bardeen-pf1k0

I hope I could explain, my english is not well.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please put the code in the question as a [mcve] to avoid link rot. Thanks!

Comment: There are a few things to do. 1. Do not filter the games in search page. 2. Pass the search text to the context and get it in the Card component.

Comment: @SelvaS How can I do?